# Как расположить flex элементы в две строки?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как расположить flex элементы в 2 строки, чтобы получилось вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую свойство `flex-wrap`, но что-то не получается - последние элементы не прижимаются к экрану и остаётся отступ:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.photos {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.photos__img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <p>наши фото</p>
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=7">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=8">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=9">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=10">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего сложного - задайте выравнивание и укажите правильные размеры:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.photos {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.photos__img {
  width: 19%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px red;
}

.photos__img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <p>наши фото</p>
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=7">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=8">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=9">
    </div>
    <div class="photos__img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=10">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```